# PHP populate textbox from MySQL and update back

Tags: php, mysql, forms, textbox, sql-update

Im trying to do an update form, I retrieve some fields from MySQL and then I want to update them in the same TextBox or textarea that I used to display them.

After populating a TextBox or any type of input from MySQL I cant updated back because the first value is kept.

Im just putting the value that I get from MySQL doing this: `value="<?php echo $warranty ?>"`

Any suggestion on how to retrieve the second value, the one that I write on the TextBox?

CODE:

`<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name?>" required=""><br>`

This code is working perfect, I get a TextBox with the deafault value $name, the problem is that when I delete that name and write a new one and send it, it sends again this `value="<?php echo $name?>"` instead of what I wrote in the TextBox from the browser.

I know how to correctly get the values with PDO and update them too, so the problem is not between the link with the database the problem is changing the "value" of the TextBox

Comment: Loop the fetch maybe... can you provide more details. e.g. what is `$warranty`, how is that set, where is that being put, etc.

Comment: you'll need to post your full code or a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If something isn't updating, then there may be errors.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain myself very well, sorry for that, what details do you need?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Im going to post code right now. sorry for the inconvenient

Comment: @Fred-ii- there goes the code, I wanted to upload pics but due to reputation I cant, hope you understand now, if not, please tell me what else should I post. thanks for yor help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$warranty = !empty($_POST['warranty']) ? $_POST['warranty'] : $warranty;
value="<?php echo $warranty; ?>"
```